# Can the Constructible Universe be built in absence of Unions and Power?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructibility

Can $L$ be built in

[$\sf ZF$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) $\sf-Regularity-Union-Power+ Boolean \ Union$?

We know that $L$ can be built in $\sf KP$, but here we don't have Set Union.

If the answer is to the negative, then would adding $\sf Cartesian \ products; Ordinal \ Union$ and $\sf Global \ Choice$, enable a positive answer?

**Ordinal union** stipulates that if $X$ is a set of ordinals, then set union of $X$ exists.

If we can recover $L$ in the latter theory, then if we add the axiom of $\sf Successor \ cardinals$ (i.e. for every cardinal $\kappa$ there is a cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\kappa < \lambda$), would that lead to $L \models \sf ZFC$?